# apache 2.2 + php 5.3 + mysql problem

Tags: php, mysql, apache2

i install php 5.3, apache 2.2, mysql at windows 2008. everything works ok except phpmyadmin not. Mysql server works ok. And if i run

http://89.212.111.174/raing.si/phpinfo.php

show php version 5.2 but i install 5.3.6.

if i run

http://89.212.111.174/raing.si/phpmyadmin

i get error. mysql and mysqli are uncomented in phpini.

What is wrong here?

Comment: Have you installed the PHP in directory `C:\Program Files\PHP`?

Comment: Do you also have a different webserver running that's taking priority? That your PHP version reports incorrectly and that phpmyadmin isn't working for you is a dead giveaway for that.

Comment: yes i install php in directory C:\Program Files\PHP

Answer (score 0):

Restart Apache. then simply create a file like

```
<?php
echo phpinfo();
?>
```

run that file it display all information.

Answer (score -1):

Restart Apache, that might do it. I do not see mysql on your `phpinfo()` page.

Answer (score -1):

It seems you haven't installed the [MySQL PHP module](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php).

Comment: His phpinfo is also a symptom of the problem, as it shows the wrong version. Its information is not reliable.

Comment: Well, `phpinfo()` MUST be using the version of PHP installed on the server, so the version which the OP believes is installed is clearly not what is actually installed.

Comment: Not if he's accidentally running two servers, and invoking HTTP requests to the wrong one.